# Can't access Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I was trying to change the network numbers address of my Virtual machine on Azure to be in same network rang as another Virtual machine on Azure pool, once I click save on network card, it freezes & became not accessible with Remote Desktop or any other way.

Please Help.

Comment: This might be better asked on ServerFault than here since its not a programming question.  However it strikes me as fairly sensible that when you change the network address of a VM - your remote desktop fails, since it is connected to the old address/port.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER try to manually change the NIC. The NIC is still owned by the Windows Azure fabric and when you manually make changes, the fabric interprets it as an attempt to bypass its network security measure. You should be able to get access to the VM back by removing and re-adding the VM (when you remove it, be sure not to remove its disks then you can re-provision it from those same disks).

If you're trying to adjust network address spaces (subnets?), you may want to look at using an Azure virtual network to help group VMs together. While this still won't guarantee a fixed internal IP address, it will give you a degree of predictability.